# How to set default value or binding for datetime to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to put a default value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" in but first it does not allow me.

So I then tried to put "1/1/0001" but when I test it. It gets changed to (((1)/(1))/(1)) and when I try out the default value it gives back "01/02/1900 12:00:00 AM" I am not sure why.

Comment: Why are you doing this (putting in a meaningless date) rather than just allowing NULL?

Comment: So I don't have to check for Null values later on when my linq to sql gets it back(another if statement check that could be avoided). I am just using this date as check to see if their account is still valid. If if it defaults to something like 1900 then it will always be invalid till they buy a subscription.

Comment: So instead you're going to do an IF check to see if it's 1/1/0001?  I don't understand the gain.

Comment: No instead of checking first it it has a value(ie not null) then checking to see if the date is greater than now. I just can skip the checking if it has a value and see if the date is greater than now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of `datetime` in SQL Server is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999. If you want 1/1/0001 as a value, you must use `datetime2` in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Ah ok well then I will try then Jan 1, 1753

Comment: Ok it changed 1/1/1753 to (((1)/(1))/(1753)) and default value still is 01/02/1900

Comment: Maybe you should use "1753-01-01".

Comment: Yep. `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName DEFAULT '1753-01-01' FOR ColumnName` works for me.

Comment: It really likes 1900's. I tried 1753-01-01 and it started to make ones with 1904

Comment: I guess I will stick with 1900. I just wanted to know why and not all of a sudden it gives something greater than 2010

Comment: @chobo2. Enter it with '1753-01-01' in quotes so it doesn't think it is a mathematical expression. (The first attempt being a division the second one being subtraction). It is doing 1753-01-01=1751 then  DATEADD(DAY,1751,'1900-01-01') when casting 1751 to a date. Which is why you get `1904-10-18`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id INT, aDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT('1753-01-01'))
```

Or, if you want to get "fancy", you could try this:

```
CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DefaultDate] AS '1753-01-01'
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyDate] FROM [datetime] NOT NULL
GO

EXEC sys.sp_bindefault 
  @defname=N'[dbo].[DefaultDate]', 
  @objname=N'[dbo].[MyDate]' 
GO

CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id INT, aDate [MyDate] NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable (ID) SELECT 1
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

**[EDIT]** 
  Like Martin Smith very well noticed, sp_bindefault is going to be deleted in a future version ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177503.aspx) ). So, use the first solution to have less headaches with the future upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

First, `DateTime` data types can only store a minimum date of '1753-01-01'. For `SmallDateTime`, the minimum date is '1900-01-01'. It is not an accident that they chose this value. The calendar itself changed in 1752 and thus trying to compare the number of days from say '1701-01-01' to now is problematic using standard date math.

However, in SQL Server 2008, there a new `DateTime2` or `Date` either of which can store a value of `0001-01-01` but it would be mistake to do so for the reason I just mentioned.

Third, trying to use an arbitrary date to represent the absence of a date value is a mistake IMO. This is what I call the "magic value" approach to avoiding nulls. IMO, it greatly complicates the calling code as the calling code now has to know about and check for the magic value instead of a null to know whether to display a blank. Instead, you should return nullable DateTime values (`DateTime?`) from your LINQ code and pass that null all the way to the presentation tier so that the presentation code can deal with absent values.or